# How to find state-space representation of quadcopter?

Tags: quadcopter

I want to design a linear controller for a quadcopter which is 6dof nonlinear.

I have non-linear equations. But in order to design a linear controller, I need to find a linear state-space model of the vehicle.

I skimmed bunch of articles and thesis without any result. Most of them have some approximations for separate parts of the model to linearize.

I need the state-space as a form like below,

$$\dot{x}=Ax(t)+Bu(t)$$

I couldn't find the $A$ and $B$ matrices. I made the small angle and hover condition approximations so that equations become simpler yet they are still non-linear.

Non-simplified equations are as follow,
[image]

Comment: If you want to determine the A and B matrices, take a look at [1](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Linear_System_Solutions). If you want to see your 6 dof quadcopter in the air and fly autonomously use a "timed behaviortree".

Comment: For ? The question seems to be incomplete.

Comment: Your system is still nonlinear. You may take a look at [Full linear control of a quadrotor UAV, LQ vs H](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6915128/)

Comment: @GürkanÇetin For u silmeyi unutmuşum :).[Turkish] I have forgotten to delete the "For".[English]

Comment: @GürkanÇetin how can I contact with you if possible? I am not sure if we start a chat here.

Comment: @CroCo your reference was very helpful to get the linear model of the quadrotor with a few exceptions. A matrix indicated in the reference is not correct. The gravity variable should be one column before where it is now. And can't find the way to put the "-g" located in the $$\ddot{Z}=-g+\frac{U_1}{m}$$ equation in matrix A.

Comment: did someone do state space of the quadcopter?

Answer (score 3):

[image]
**State-space equations for your case.**